# Retain title and icon on navigation drawer

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, navigation-drawer

I'm currently using Vue and vuetify to build a navigation drawer container. I have just about what I am looking for... However, when I click on the drawer icon, I lose the Title and the drawer icon. I want those to both stay there even when the drawer is open.

Is there any way to achieve this by using simply vuetify? I can obviously add a custom title in and then add an icon in as well. Here is my code and here are some screenshots to better help with what I'm trying to achieve. I've looked through the documentation, and I've also looked at the props for the navigation drawer. Hoping someone has a good workaround. [image]
[image]

code:

```
<template>
  <v-card height="100%" flat>
    <v-app-bar elevation="0" class="transparent">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="drawer = true"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>{{ Title }}</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer prepend v-model="drawer" absolute temporary>
      <v-list nav dense>
        <v-list-item-group
          v-model="group"
          active-class="blue--text text--accent-4"
        >
          <v-list-item @click="setTitle(TitleList[0])" to="/home">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Home</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item @click="setTitle(TitleList[1])" to="/about">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>About</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item @click="setTitle(TitleList[2])" to="/investments">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-currency-usd</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Investments</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item @click="setTitle(TitleList[3])" to="/contact">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-email</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Contact</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      group: null,
      Title: "Home",
      TitleList: ["Home", "About", "Investments", "Contact"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setTitle(value) {
      this.Title = value;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem will be solved if do not passing `absolute` prop for `v-navigation-drawer`.

Comment: Seems to almost be there. That grays out the screen even more when clicked, and the left navbar doesn't extend all the way up on the screen (stops at the title and icon)